# Suggestions for using Nginx web server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, html

We recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows, and I am here to seek suggestions and recommendations for my use case.

I have installed Nginx web server on my Ubuntu VM (`my_server_name`) and we would like to serve several HTML files via Nginx to display in a front-end application. The HTML files content is mainly based on maps and animations, and some HTML files also have associated JS and CSS files. There can be many concurrent users of the front-end app at the same time.

Several Nginx tutorial links over the Internet recommends creating server blocks. My question is, do I need server blocks for my use case? or is it appropriate to dump all HTML files inside `/var/www/html` directory to display in front end app?

I have checked Nginx wiki and docs for optimization and tuning tips, but would very appreciate and welcome suggestions and recommendations for my use-case scenario.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ is probably a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Since you mention VM, is it strictly local / vm only or public internet use case?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-the-default-document-root

Comment: @frostschutz: I have seen the link that you shared. It's a VM behind network firewall but public access may be allowed on some ports.

Comment: `do I need server blocks` yes, you need at least one server block - you need multiple server blocks if you want to serve multiple domains - server blocks are nginx term for Apache's "virtualHost" - see example of server blocks in nginx documentation (don't bother with tutorials unless you happen upon a good one - most internet tutorials are complete garbage - always reference documentation first before simply accepting that a tutorial is in any way valid)

Comment: @Bravo: Bravo for your detailed reply! :) Did you mean to say I need to put my HTML files in a server block and not in `var/www/html`? Do you suggest to divide those various HTML files in two or three server blocks. Not sure if I understood by "multiple domains", I only one sever with a cool name..